# How to access a ordered list's anchor tag and change the "href" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How do I change the HREF for an anchor tag that is inside an ordered list? More specifically, how do I change the HREF of the anchor tag in my specific case where the list is appended to the body?

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
var image = document.createElement("img");
image.src = "http://archiveteam.org/images/1/15/Apple-logo.jpg"
image.className = "image";
var aboutMe = document.createElement("p");
aboutMe.innerHTML = "Hello";
aboutMe.className = "Border";
var movies = ["Inception", "Remember the Titans", "Happy Gilmore", "Interstellar", "The Martian"]
var listOfMovies = document.createElement("ol");
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var anchor = document.createElement("a");
  anchor.href = "#";
  anchor.innerHTML = movies[i];
  var bullets = document.createElement("li");
  bullets.appendChild(anchor);
  listOfMovies.appendChild(bullets);
}

listOfMovies.getElementsByTagName("li")[0].href = 'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1375666/';
listOfMovies.getElementsByTagName("li")[1].href = 'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0210945/';
listOfMovies.getElementsByTagName("li")[2].href = 'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116483/';
listOfMovies.getElementsByTagName("li")[3].href = 'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0816692/';
listOfMovies.getElementsByTagName("li")[4].href = 'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3659388/';

document.body.appendChild(image);
document.body.appendChild(aboutMe);
document.body.appendChild(listOfMovies)

listOfMovies.className = "Border"
```

Comment: put ur's in another array in same order as `movies` , include href property in your loop for each `anchor`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the `li` element's href attribute instead of the `a` (anchor) element.  So your first line of code to change the href should be:

```
listOfMovies.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].href = 'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1375666/';
```

You could also iterate through this list to have simpler code by adding the href's to an array in the same order as movies or even creating a movies object with Movie title and url like:

```
movies = [{ title: "Inception", url: "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1375666/" },{...}...];
```

Comment: As an aside, a more programmatic way to the limit parameter of your `for` loop would be `i < movies.length;` which would allow for any number of movies to be iterated through giving your code extensibility.

Comment: Thank you, just a dumb mistake. As for your second answer, that seems like a great way of doing it and much more efficient. I am going to play around with that and see if I can get it working in my code. Thank you!